# Matplotlib spectrogram intensity legend (colorbar)

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I'm using matplotlib's `specgram` function to generate a spectrogram. I've attempted to include a colorbar off to the right of the spectrogram to give an indication of dB-to-color-mapping.

For some reason though, the dB indicated by the colorbar do not make sense.

Perhaps I've not generated the colorbar correctly? Perhaps there is some parameter that I need to pass to specgram?

The signal I'm generating is a 1Khz, 2Vpp sine sampled at 32Khz.

I'm expecting that the dark red peak on the spectrogram corresponds to 0dB (Meaning that +1V is my reference)

Anybody have any idea what is wrong with my approach?

```
def plot_specgram(data, title='', x_label='', y_label='', fig_size=None):
    fig = plt.figure()
    if fig_size != None:
        fig.set_size_inches(fig_size[0], fig_size[1])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
    pxx,  freq, t, cax = plt.specgram(data, Fs=32000)
    fig.colorbar(cax).set_label('Intensity [dB]')

plot_specgram(a,title='Spectrogram', x_label='time (in seconds)', y_label='frequency', fig_size=(14,8))
```

This is what I get as resulting spectrogram:

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: From the color map, the dark red *does* seem to correspond to 0. Just that 0 isn't displayed... The 0db ( dark red ) corresponds to the peak spectral component of 1kHz... The blue, as expected has a lower intensity value ( << 0 ) since they are just artifacts developed due to sampling... I frankly do not see anything wrong with your code / graph...

Comment: Actually, probably, what you're seeing is the result of a window function that you aren't taking into account. I'm pretty sure `specgram` uses a Hanning window as the default, which may mess with what you expect from your scaling.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, please supply your `a` vector, since it seems to have some kind of harmonics.

This is a bit trial and error, but this seems to produce the correct scaling:

```
NFFT = 256
ax.specgram(x/(NFFT/2), NFFT=NFFT, Fs=fs, mode='magnitude', window=plt.window_none)
```

Using a window seems to lose about 1/2 of the peak power, you can of course adjust for this.

A complete example where I have limited the dynamic range to 40dB (as an example, if you want to hide the small stuff).

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# generate a 1kHz sine wave
fs = 32e3
t = np.arange(0, 15, 1.0/fs)
f0 = 1e3
A = 1
x = A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
vmin = 20*np.log10(np.max(x)) - 40  # hide anything below -40 dBc
cmap.set_under(color='k', alpha=None)

NFFT = 256
pxx,  freq, t, cax = ax.specgram(x/(NFFT/2), Fs=fs, mode='magnitude',
                                 NFFT=NFFT, noverlap=NFFT/2,
                                 vmin=vmin, cmap=cmap,
                                 window=plt.window_none)
fig.colorbar(cax)

print np.max(pxx) # should match A
```

[image: resulting image]

Comment: What is NFFT and why is the value 256 there?

Comment: @MartinThoma It is a input argument to ax.specgram that controls the number of frequencies to calculate the spectogram for, we need to divide by this number to scale the plot correctly. See the spectogram documentation for the math.